# how are instances sorted in Berkeley Caffe

Tags: python, batch-processing, caffe

i wonder how instances are sorted and fed to the neural network in Berkeley Caffe.

Let's say I create an lmbd database and save 10 images to it - image 1 to 10. Let's assume this is the python code I use to create the lmbd database.

```
import lmbd
imgs = [img_1,img_2,img_3,img_4, img_5,img_6,img_7,img_8,img_9,img_10] 

def make_datum(img, label):
    #image is numpy.ndarray format. BGR instead of RGB
    return caffe_pb2.Datum(
        channels=3,
        width=224,
        height=224,
        data=np.rollaxis(img, 2).tostring())

train_lmdb = '../train_lmdb/'
in_db = lmdb.open(train_lmdb, map_size=int(1e12))
k = 0
with in_db.begin(write=True) as in_txn:
    for idx, img_path in enumerate(imgs):
    if idx % 10 == 0:
            continue
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        datum = make_datum(img)
        in_txn.put('{:0>8d}'.format(idx), datum.SerializeToString())
in_db.close()
```

Let's assume batch size is 5 (database size is 10).

**Can I safely assume that the first batch will include images 1 to 5 (in that order) and the second batch images 6 to 10 (in that order)?**

Comment: as long as you do not use [`rand_skip`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L655) parameter

Comment: once more, thanks a lot Shai